# How to remove background color in Powershell within SSH session

Tags: powershell, ssh

When I use terminal to connect to my machine, the background just turn black and overwrite the default color of my terminal.

[image]

My other machines don't do this.

I've compared the **Powershell version** and **PSReadline version**(`Get-Module PSReadline`) between these machines.

**The problem one**: `PSVersion 5.1.14393.206` and `PSReadline 1.2`

**Others**: `PSVersion 5.1.19041.1320` and `PSReadline 2.0.0`

(**14393** and **19041** are build version).

`Get-PSReadLineOption` gave:

[image]

which is different from PSReadline 2.0.0 Options (it doesn't have `xxxBackgroundColor`). And turns out `xxxBackgroundColor` cannot be set to something like null/None (or am I wrong?).

- I zipped my PSReadline 2.0.0 folder and uploaded it to the problem machine and did some work. `Get-Module PSReadline` DOES give `2.0.0` now, but the problem is still there.
- Updating the **build version of Powershell** seems impossible, so I would not know if it's **PSVersion** that caused this.
- ssh config files bewteen these machines are the same.

And ideas?

(And sorry for my poor English)

### Update

Answers mentioned in Martin's comment solved the original problem, which is about **paramiko + SSHClient + duplicated output**.